# How to debug CSS when using GWT

Tags: css, debugging, gwt

How do you guys debug CSS when using `ClientBundle`s in GWT given that CSS class names are obfuscated. I'm using a `CellTable` and some rows have up to 4-5 class names.

Is there a way to `@export` all these classes in a certain CSS file? I  don't want to explicitly export them all, even with an automated way of extracting the class names. Maybe, just as a last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: there should be a build porperty which then displayes the css properties in a more clear way, or so I've heared. I think it was in one of the videos where they are talking about GWT and Google Wave and the experiences they made. In the end someone asks this question and he tells him about the "flag". If you find it please post it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `gwt.xml` file,

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="pretty" />
```

See the CssResource docs at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Levers_and_Knobs

Comment: Is there a way to have this property enabled only in development mode without creating an additional gwt.xml file?

Comment: There's no way to automatically switch for DevMode vs. production mode.

Answer (score 0):

For those who find this on Google, I just created and released a cross browser tool that allows you to visualize your HTML / CSS layout just by moving the mouse.  You can visualize your elements and find problems as you move around the page as usual.

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)